# Почему не сработала функция?

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы  функция t2 возвращала переменную a2.

Где я ошибился ?

```js
let a2 = 843;

function t2() {
  return a2
}
document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.out-2').textContent = f2();
}
```

```html
<button class="b-2">B-2</button>
<div class="out-2">test2</div>
```

Comment: Вот здесь ошибся:  textContent = f2()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f2()` → `t2()`

```js
let a2 = 843;

function t2() {
  return a2
}
document.querySelector('.b-2').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.out-2').textContent = t2();
}
```

```html
<button class="b-2">B-2</button>
<div class="out-2">test2</div>
```